# $elem..style.display always returns empty string

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have this website:
https://www.jamesandrose.co.uk/

I'm trying to figure out a way to see if the element #cookie-law-info-bar is visible or not.

Normal is('visible') doesn't work on Chrome so I'm trying to read the inline styling directly to see if it contains display: none or display: block.

I've added this script:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  var style = $("#cookie-law-info-bar")[0].style
  console.log(style)
  var display = $("#cookie-law-info-bar")[0].style.display
  console.log(display)
});
```

This is the output in the console:
[image]

No matter what I do, whether $elem.style.cssText or $elem.style.backgroundColor the result is always an empty string.

Totally lost my sanity, any help appreciated.

Comment: `is(':visible')`.  You forgot the `:`.  Also, display will be blank if the element is visible.  It would be 'none' if it were not visible.  Though that ignores that an element could be placed offscreen, or z-indexed under stuff, or opacity set to 0.

Comment: I went to your site on chrome, and the cookie banner was up on the bottom.  I ran `jQuery("#cookie-law-info-bar").is(':visible')` in the console and it came back true.

Comment: it always returns true, even if you accept cookies and refresh

Comment: adding a timeout fixed the problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have visited your website and I tried the following code.

```
document.querySelector("#cookie-law-info-bar").style.display // returend block
```

Once try this

Comment: weird, that returns blank string for me also

Comment: wait, if I do this inside a timeout, it works, thanks for your help